# Extract more than one type of element whilst preserving order using rvest (or similar) in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, rvest, xml2

I'm attempting to extract elements matching 2 different types in an HTML document, whilst preserving the order.

It's straight forward to extract each element type separately (see example), but I cannot work out how to extract them both in one go and preserve the order in which they appear in the web page.

#### Minimal example

Here's some dummy HTML

```
dummy_html <- "<p>hi there</p>
<p>2nd para</p>
<div>unwanted stuff</div>
<span>something new</span>
<p>3rd para</p>
<span>extra stuff</span>
<div>more unwanted stuff</div>
<p>4th para</p>"
```

Suppose we wish to extract all the `p` elements and all the `span` elements (and maintain the order in which they appear)

```
# p elements on their own
library(rvest)
dummy_html %>% read_html %>% html_nodes("p")

{xml_nodeset (4)}
[1] <p>hi there</p>
[2] <p>2nd para</p>
[3] <p>3rd para</p>
[4] <p>4th para</p>

# span elements on their own
dummy_html %>% read_html %>% html_nodes("span")
{xml_nodeset (2)}
[1] <span>something new</span>
[2] <span>extra stuff</span>
```

But how can we extract all of **either** element? i.e. all the p elements and all the span elements ***together*** so that the desired output is:

```r
{xml_nodeset (6)}
[1] <p>hi there</p>
[2] <p>2nd para</p>
[3] <span>something new</span>
[4] <p>3rd para</p>
[5] <span>extra stuff</span>
[6] <p>4th para</p>
```

Note the preservation of the order (i.e. `p` and `span` interspliced)

#### What I've tried so far

I tried the obvious `dummy_html %>% read_html %>% html_nodes("span|p")` but it throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with either CSS or XPath syntax; your CSS just needed a `,` instead of a `|`:

```r
  library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2

  dummy_html <- "<p>hi there</p>
<p>2nd para</p>
<div>unwanted stuff</div>
<span>something new</span>
<p>3rd para</p>
<span>extra stuff</span>
<div>more unwanted stuff</div>
<p>4th para</p>"

  # With CSS
  dummy_html %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("p,span")
#> {xml_nodeset (6)}
#> [1] <p>hi there</p>
#> [2] <p>2nd para</p>
#> [3] <span>something new</span>
#> [4] <p>3rd para</p>
#> [5] <span>extra stuff</span>
#> [6] <p>4th para</p>
  # With XPath
  dummy_html %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//span | //p")
#> {xml_nodeset (6)}
#> [1] <p>hi there</p>
#> [2] <p>2nd para</p>
#> [3] <span>something new</span>
#> [4] <p>3rd para</p>
#> [5] <span>extra stuff</span>
#> [6] <p>4th para</p>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Thanks to QHarr for pointing out the (neater) CSS option!